# How to update a javascript variable for everyone?

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for a way to turn a JavaScript variable into a server-side variable so that when it is changed it is changed for everyone visiting the site. I'm really struggling to find a way to do this. Thank you <3!

Basically, I'm making a simple "How many times this button has been pressed"

```js
var clicks = 0; //increment this by one every click


function update_total_clicks() {
    var e = document.getElementById("total_clicks");
    e.innerHTML = 'Clicks: ' + clicks;
}

document.getElementById("click").onclick =    function() {  
    clicks++; 
    update_total_clicks(); //updates the text
};
```

```html
    <button id="click" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
        click me!
    </button>
    <div id="total_clicks">Clicks: 0</div>
```

Problem is, total clicks is only shown to current user, not to all users. I want the total clicks to be visible by everyone.

Comment: Would you please submit some of your codes what you did till now!

Comment: Do you know how to use Ajax requests? Do you have a server running?

Comment: Show the code pls. it's pretty hard to advise something without seeing the code

Comment: Can you add code?  You need to send the variable to the backend.  Do you know how to make one?

Comment: You need a server and maybe a database also. What have you tried so far? Please elaborate

Answer (score 0):

**There are many ways to archive this, but I would recommend WebSockets.**

In any case, you will need some script running on the server that communicates with the Javascript in the user's browser. This server script would receive the changed variable from one browser and then send it to the others etc.

<s>The best answer here highly depends on your application, and it will probably not be straight forward.</s> Based on your example code, I would suggest you take a look at WebSockets.
It's an easy to use protocol that opens a connection between the browser and the server outside of the usual http(s).
For your Javascript in the browser, there is a [simple API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_client_applications) to connect to the server and to send and receive messages. For the server side, there are implementations for many languages (e. g. Python, Javascript using `node.js`, C++, Java, ...), and I would recommend you choose whatever you're most comfortable with.